# Is it possible for Android to return the number of samples per some X time from the touch screen?

Tags: android

Basically, I am trying to write a benchmark application to test the responsiveness of different Android devices' touchscreens.  I figured the best way to go about doing this is to write an application that counts the number of samples returned from the touchscreen whenever it is touched.  Unfortunately, I have no idea if this is possible and so far haven't found anything relevant to this idea.

I will most likely be using the MotionEvent class to determine when the touch screen is pressed, but what classes are available to determine the samples returned?

This is how I imagine my app to function:

- Start app
- Brief description screen, then button to begin testing
- User touches an area of the screen
- I haven't really determined how to do the output yet, but either part of the screen updates a real time graph, or the user just touches for some time and after he releases his finger from the screen, the app will output a new graph in a different activity.

Any help would be useful.
Thanks!

Comment: The number of motion events you receive will be highly dependent on how fast the user moves his finger.  It might be helpful to animate a dot or circle on the screen that the user follows with his finger.

Comment: Would you recommend just using getHistorySize() or is there a better way to do this?  

I was hoping for a more low-level like data sample capture, like how fast Android is interpreting the values received by the touchscreen (for example, if the touchscreen is being sampled at 1 sample/10ms, how fast is the OS capturing those samples and interpreting them?  Although, a higher level use would be ok for now.